# How to multiply 2 double[][] matrices using streams?

Tags: java, math, matrix, java-stream, matrix-multiplication

I'm wondering what the most compact and efficient way to multiple 2 `double[][]` arrays matrices using streams. The approach should follow matrix multiplication rules as illustrated here:

[Matrix Multiplication: How to Multiply Two Matrices Together](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/matrix/multiply-matrix.php)

Here's one way to do it using for loops (`this` is the first matrix):

```java
final int nRows = this.getRowDimension();
final int nCols = m.getColumnDimension();
final int nSum = this.getColumnDimension();

final double[][] outData = new double[nRows][nCols];
// Will hold a column of "m".
final double[] mCol = new double[nSum];
final double[][] mData = m.data;

// Multiply.
for (int col = 0; col < nCols; col++) {
    // Copy all elements of column "col" of "m" so that
    // will be in contiguous memory.
    for (int mRow = 0; mRow < nSum; mRow++) {
        mCol[mRow] = mData[mRow][col];
    }

    for (int row = 0; row < nRows; row++) {
        final double[] dataRow = data[row];
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nSum; i++) {
            sum += dataRow[i] * mCol[i];
        }
        outData[row][col] = sum;
    }
}
```

The procedure should fit the following test data:

```java
double[][] md1 = {{4d, 8d}, {0d, 2d}, {1d, 6d}};
double[][] md2 = {{5d, 2d, 5d, 5d}, {9d, 4d, 5d, 5d}};

double[][] mb1 = {{4d, 8d}, {0d, 2d}, {1d, 6d}};
double[][] mb2 = {{5d}, {9d}};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A more compact and readable solution is to create a Stream over the rows of the first matrix, map each row to the result of multiplying it with the second matrix column and collect that back into a `double[][]`.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[][] m1 = {{4, 8}, {0, 2}, {1, 6}};
    double[][] m2 = {{5, 2}, {9, 4}};

    double[][] result = Arrays.stream(m1)
            .map(r -> IntStream.range(0, m2[0].length)
                    .mapToDouble(i -> IntStream.range(0, m2.length)
                            .mapToDouble(j -> r[j] * m2[j][i]).sum())
                    .toArray())
            .toArray(double[][]::new);

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(result));
    // [[92.0, 40.0], [18.0, 8.0], [59.0, 26.0]]
}
```

This will calculate `m1 * m2` and the result will be in `result`. For the multiplication of each row, we can't create a Stream with [`Arrays.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-) of the second matrix since this would create a Stream over the rows when we need a Stream over the columns. To counteract that, we simply go back to using an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) over the indexes.

Answer (score 1):

I created a BiFunction that performs the multiplication using `IntStream.range()`. If anyone has anything more compact I would love to see it. Here it is:

```java
public static BiFunction<ArrayMatrix, ArrayMatrix, ArrayMatrix> multiply(boolean parallel) {
    return (m1, m2) -> {
        // checkMultiplicationCompatible(m1, m2);
        final int m1Rows = m1.getRowDimension();
        final int m2Rows = m2.getRowDimension();
        final int m1Cols = m1.getColumnDimension();
        final int m2Cols = m2.getColumnDimension();

        double[][] a1 = m1.getData();
        double[][] a2 = m2.getData();

        final double[][] result = new double[m1Rows][m2Cols];

        // Buffer for the tranpose of each md2 column
        final double[] transpose = new double[m1Rows];

        range(0, m2Cols).forEach(m2Col -> {
            range(0, m2Rows).forEach(m2Row -> {
                transpose[m2Row] = a2[m2Row][m2Col];
            });
            range(0, m1Rows).forEach(row -> {
                final double[] dataRow = a1[row];
                double sum = 0;
                for (int m1Col = 0; m1Col < m1Cols; m1Col++) {
                    sum += dataRow[m1Col] * transpose[m1Col];
                }
                result[row][m2Col] = sum;
            });
        });
        return new ArrayMatrix(result, false);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use three nested [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html)s to multiply two matrices. Outer stream iterates over the rows of the *first matrix* and the inner stream iterates over the columns of the *second matrix* to build the *result matrix*. The innermost stream obtains the *entries* of the *result matrix*. Each *entry* is the sum of the products obtained by multiplying the *i*-th row of the *first matrix* and the *j*-th column of the *second matrix*:

```java
/**
 * Matrix multiplication
 *
 * @param m rows of 'a' matrix
 * @param n columns of 'a' matrix
 *          and rows of 'b' matrix
 * @param p columns of 'b' matrix
 * @param a first matrix 'm×n'
 * @param b second matrix 'n×p'
 * @return result matrix 'm×p'
 */
public static double[][] matrixMultiplication(
        int m, int n, int p, double[][] a, double[][] b) {
    return IntStream.range(0, m)
            .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, p)
                    .mapToDouble(j -> IntStream.range(0, n)
                            .mapToDouble(k -> a[i][k] * b[k][j])
                            .sum())
                    .toArray())
            .toArray(double[][]::new);
}
```

---

```java
// test
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[][] md1 = {{4d, 8d}, {0d, 2d}, {1d, 6d}};
    double[][] md2 = {{5d, 2d, 5d, 5d}, {9d, 4d, 5d, 5d}};
    double[][] md3 = matrixMultiplication(3, 2, 4, md1, md2);

    Arrays.stream(md3).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
    //[92.0, 40.0, 60.0, 60.0]
    //[18.0, 8.0, 10.0, 10.0]
    //[59.0, 26.0, 35.0, 35.0]

    //// //// //// //// //// //// //// ////

    double[][] mb1 = {{4d, 8d}, {0d, 2d}, {1d, 6d}};
    double[][] mb2 = {{5d}, {9d}};
    double[][] mb3 = matrixMultiplication(3, 2, 1, mb1, mb2);

    Arrays.stream(mb3).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
    //[92.0]
    //[18.0]
    //[59.0]
}
```

---

<sup>See also: [Parallelized Matrix Multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66000825/14940971)</sup>