# How to use streams to find pairs of elements from two lists or array multiplication

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream, cartesian-product

I have two lists of numbers and I'd like to find all possible pairs of numbers. For example, given the lists `[1, 2, 3]` and `[3, 4]` the result should be:

```
[(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 3), (3, 4)]
```

I know I can do this using a *for loop* but is there any more concise way to do it using *Java 8 streams*?

I tried the following, but I'm missing something as I'm getting `List<Stream<int[]>>` instead of `List<int[]>`.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
    List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(3, 4);
    List<int[]> pairs = list1.stream()
                             .map(i -> list2.stream()
                                            .map(j -> new int[]{i, j}))
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
    pairs.forEach(i -> {
        System.out.println("{" + i[0] + "," + i[1] + "}");
    });
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34784924/1849366

Comment: This Worked on using flatMap()

Comment: You probably want to look at something about Cartesian product. But in this case I'd recommend to have two for loops as it's going to be far more readable, than any java 8 stream magic.

Comment: @evgenii Yes, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32131987/how-can-i-make-cartesian-product-with-java-8-streams (might be duplicate...)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all possible combinations from two arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53780951/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-from-two-arrays)

Comment: Duplicate: [How do I generate combinations of two arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65169699/how-do-i-generate-combinations-of-two-arrays)

Answer (score 17):

Use **flatMap()** method instead of **map()**, it will combine the streams into one.
Refer : [Difference Between map() and flatMap()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26684582/5803493) and [flatMap() example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22382453/5803493)

Comment: Accepting this as a answer as it provides links also to get more information on flatMap

Comment: Bring that information here instead of hiding it behind links

Answer (score 14):

You just need to replace your first `map()` with [`flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-).

Answer (score 14):

Here is a solution using `IntStream` with two `int` arrays as the source instead of `List<Integer>`.  I wanted to see if it was possible to solve this problem without boxing every `int` as an `Integer`.

```
int[] one = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
int[] two = new int[]{3, 4};
List<IntIntPair> list = new ArrayList<>();
IntStream.of(one).forEach(i ->
        IntStream.of(two).mapToObj(j -> PrimitiveTuples.pair(i, j)).forEach(list::add));
System.out.println(list);
// [1:3, 1:4, 2:3, 2:4, 3:3, 3:4]
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't use `flatMap` on `IntStream` as it returns an `IntStream`.  There is no `flatMapToObj` currently on `IntStream`, which is what would be needed here.  So I used `forEach` instead.

The `IntIntPair` and [`PrimitiveTuples`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/10.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/tuple/primitive/PrimitiveTuples.html) classes I used from [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/), as they made it simpler to just output the list as a string.  You could use `int[]` as you have in your solution.  The code would look as follows.

```
List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
IntStream.of(one).forEach(i ->
        IntStream.of(two).mapToObj(j -> new int[]{i, j}).forEach(list::add));
```

In the 8.1 release of Eclipse Collections (to be released mid-March), there is now a `flatCollect` method on all primitive containers in the library which can be used to solve this problem.  This essentially does what a `flatMapToObj` method on `IntStream` should do.

```
IntList a = IntLists.mutable.with(1, 2, 3);
IntList b = IntLists.mutable.with(3, 4);
List<IntIntPair> result =
        a.flatCollect(
                i -> b.collect(j -> PrimitiveTuples.pair(i, j)),
                Lists.mutable.empty());
System.out.println(result);
// [1:3, 1:4, 2:3, 2:4, 3:3, 3:4]
```

**Update:**

As pointed out in the comments by Boris the Spider, the `forEach` solution would not be thread-safe and would break if the `IntStream` was `parallel`.  The following solution should work in serial or parallel.  I'm glad this was pointed out, because I hadn't thought to do a `mapToObj` on the `IntStream` and then followed by a `flatMap`.

```
int[] one = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
int[] two = new int[]{3, 4};
List<int[]> list = IntStream.of(one).parallel()
        .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.of(two).mapToObj(j -> new int[]{i, j}))
        .flatMap(e -> e)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
list.stream().map(e -> "{" + e[0] + "," + e[1] + "}").forEach(System.out::println);
```

Note: I am a committer for [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/).

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case using `flatMap` you can even bypass an array creation and make your code simpler like this:

```
list1.stream()
     .flatMap(i -> list2.stream().map(j -> "{" + i+ "," + j + "}"))
     .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//return pair of numbers
List<List<Integer>> pairs=numbers.stream()
        .flatMap(i -> numbers2.stream()
        .map(j -> Arrays.asList(i,j)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

pairs.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a 2d list of possible combinations using `map` and `reduce` methods:

```java
List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(3, 4);

List<List<Integer>> combinations = Stream.of(list1, list2)
        // represent each list element as a singleton list
        .map(list -> list.stream().map(Collections::singletonList)
                // Stream<List<List<Integer>>>
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        // intermediate output
        //[[1], [2], [3]]
        //[[3], [4]]
        .peek(System.out::println)
        // summation of pairs of inner lists
        .reduce((listA, listB) -> listA.stream()
                // combinations of inner lists
                .flatMap(inner1 -> listB.stream()
                        // merge two inner lists into one
                        .map(inner2 -> Stream.of(inner1, inner2)
                                .flatMap(List::stream)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())))
                // list of combinations
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        // otherwise an empty list
        .orElse(Collections.emptyList());

// output
System.out.println(combinations);
// [[1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 3], [3, 4]]
```

---

<sup>See also: [Generate all combinations from multiple lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67195224/15675591)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can create a `Stream` everytime in the `Stream#flatMap` but in terms of performance, it's very poor.

Instead, I'd advise you to choose for [java-16](/questions/tagged/java-16)'s `Stream#mapMulti` and operator on a more declarative way

```java
List<int[]> pairs = list1.stream()
                         .mapMulti((Integer left, Consumer<int[]> consumer) -> 
                             list2.forEach(right -> consumer.accept(new int[]{left, right})))
                         .toList();
```

Which produces the same result, without the overhead of `Stream` creation

```
{1,3}
{1,4}
{2,3}
{2,4}
{3,3}
{3,4}
```