# Permutation of Tuples

Tags: java, tuples, combinations, permutation

Let's say I have a tuple `(1, 2)`. I want to create a stream, that gives me all possible combinations of that tuples' values. So I want to create a stream that looks like this:

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

This is my class for my tuples:

```java
public class Tuple<T> {
    private final T first;
    private final T second;

    public Tuple(T first, T second) {
        assert first != null;
        assert second != null;

        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public T getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public T getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    @Override
    ...
```

This is my class for my tuple-set:

```
public class TupleSet<T> implements Set<Tuple<T>> {
    private Set<T> set;
    public TupleSet(Set<T> set) {
        this.set = set;
        //This is where I want to create my tuple-set
    }
   
    public Stream<Tuple<T>> getElements() {
    return; //This is where I want to return a stream of that tuple-set
}
```

How can I get my desired tuple-set using permutation?

I am aware, that there are multiple example for creating permutations, but I am struggeling with the `Tuple<T>`-type I have to return it in.

Tuples always have 2 elements. Although they can be created out of sets with different lenghts. If I insert the set `[0, 1, 2, 3]` I want to get that tuple list: `[(0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(0,1),(0,2)(0,3),(1,0),(1,2),(1,3),(2,0),(2,1),(2,3),(3,0)(3,1),(3,2)]` so 16 tuple values in total.

Answer (score 1):

You can pre-generate a set of all possible combinations of tuples `Set<Tuple<T>>` when creating a `TupleSet<T>` object, and then return a *stream* over that set as follows:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVNNb9swDL3nV3A5yaurotstWYwBRYsNaLGDcxt20GwmkStLhkSnGIb89ky2ZdfOx3SRST49fjy6EHtxW@Svx6MsK2MJCu/gNUnFPy5nZz5HFkXZhGZV/VvJDDIlnIMXITX8nYE/we9I0BBe15XCL@skQFqYlXtBCBuphYK1v62jGBxmRueefsB1dC0DG2DrAIxGjM3xydAX3KLgwwp0rdTyEqJ7/g6ZYGgnHe84Vh3X8jweGFZDyX30cF48bJGeGh7mCwaLVFsdiD38EjptScfwkGZM//XHHq2VOZ5SpGSl3gKZ7mNMM2dzuAkDuoF5DI0ZevF2NO8rCnmuypkiXVY0BByOpjaJhWVIABWWqMldkduD2TvZqdRBBGoVuCRQz94BwuqyaALsD98oQS@iYhJukwmcl95bNF6Nb2GREyZjKKLoCldmlMKM2EN3G@s4mWBIo9mz1K@YfxNu57tbLDxvFP1vfdK2lNHc/H48hubY6ViCzH3zQx/jBFfl3RuZQ@n/ZdYtzs9fIOzWjXMM2n/XhFu0CVDwwOpsHMPImgcJa8xJ8973LB1xs2H3MXyK4XM0HsXdHZiaqpoGT5@LT0bAN8Y@imzH0j@OsOT@0WLhV06T0oHuMDscj/8A)

```java
public static class Tuple<T> {
    private final T first, second;

    public Tuple(T first, T second) {
        assert first != null;
        assert second != null;

        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public T getFirst() { return first; }
    public T getSecond() { return second; }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return "(" + first + ", " + second + ")"; }
}
```

```java
public static class TupleSet<T> {
    private Set<T> set;
    private Set<Tuple<T>> elements;

    public TupleSet(Set<T> set) {
        this.set = set;
        this.elements = set.stream()
                .flatMap(i -> set.stream().map(j -> new Tuple<>(i, j)))
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
    }

    public Stream<Tuple<T>> getElements() {
        return elements.stream();
    }
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TupleSet<Integer> tupleSet =
            new TupleSet<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(List.of(1, 2, 3)));
    // output
    tupleSet.getElements().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Output:

```
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 1)
(2, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 1)
(3, 2)
(3, 3)
```

---

<sup>See also: [How to use streams to find pairs of elements from two lists or array multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67254159/15766209)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

A brute-force solution would be to iterate `Set<T> set` in a nested way and apply `flatMap` to create `<Stream<Tuple<T>>`:

```java
public Stream<Tuple<T>> getElements() {
    return set.stream()
            .flatMap(first -> set.stream()
                    .map(second -> new Tuple(first, second)));
}
```